# Deleting down-voted questions?

Tags: support, moderators

Is it OK to ask moderators with superpowers to delete heavily down-voted question? Where do I need to post my request? I tried to delete it but SE does not allow it because of existence of some up-voted answers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general policy across SE is to NOT delete unpopular questions. Deletion is reserved for offensive questions or spam. I'm ok with that, because heavily downvoted questions provide examples to users of how NOT to ask a question. Of course, the original poster is always free to delete their own questions.

Comment: can a poster delete his own question even if it has upvoted answers?

Comment: I'm not sure actually

Comment: Related discussion on Meta Stack Overflow: [Why cannot the original author of a question delete it when has existing answers?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11549/why-cannot-the-original-author-of-a-question-delete-it-when-has-existing-answers)

Comment: Also see [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that-actually-mean/5222#5222) for restrictions on deleting a post by its owner.

Comment: Question: does anyone know if the users who have answered the question and received upvotes loose reputation points when the question is deleted? (remember, when we are deleting a question, we are also deleting the answers.)

Comment: the links above indicate that you CANNOT delete a post with upvoted answers, for precisely the reason you mention.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, the right way to do this is to ask users who have answered your question to see if they would be OK with their answers being deleted and if so ask them to remove their answers, and after that you can delete your question yourself.